# Build up SelectList with three values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, selectlist

I need to build up a SelectList with 3 values:
StartDate,
EndDate,
String of combined Dates

I've omitted a lot of code but hopefully the snippet below will give the idea of what I want to do.
The goal is to have the select list display the string value, but have the other values there so I can use actual dates when when saving the selected option

```
public List<IntakeDateStruct> IntakeDateStructList { get; set; } = new 
List<IntakeDateStruct>();
public SelectList IntakeDates { get; set; } 

public struct IntakeDateStruct
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string TextDate { get; set; }
}

int count = 0;


foreach (var distinctDate in distinctDateList) 
{ 
    IntakeDateStructList.Add(new IntakeDateStruct()
    {
         StartDate = distinctDate.Key,
         EndDate = distinctDate.Value,
         TextDate = combinedList[count]
     });
     count++;
}
IntakeDates = new SelectList(IntakeDateStructList,
    "StartDate",
    "EndDate",
    "TextDate");
```

Comment: You don't need to include `struct` in the name of a struct. `IntakeDate` would be a more preferred name. Same with the list - collection classes are usually named with the plural of the type they contain, like `IntakeDates`.

Comment: Also, what is the question here? Is something not working? Are you getting an error or exception?

Comment: The select list has the values of StartDate. I've no idea how to access the other values, assuming the way I've coded the select list is even correct

Comment: I haven't used it, but the documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: You mean that you want to select `StartDate` and `EndDate` in the `SelectList`,then show the combine date string on the `SelectList`?And you want to pass the combine date string to the action?

Comment: At the end of the day, a select list can only post a string. The posted string is then coerced to whatever type you're actually binding it to (i.e. int). As such, you can only really use primitives as values. You can't pass a complex object or something like a struct back.